# Comprobar si los campos son correctos

Tags: java, android

Actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que se necesita rellenar un formulario con unos datos que se introducen en una BD. He desarrollado la opción para que si alguno de los campos no está lleno salga un mensaje Toast diciendo que hay que rellenar todos los campos.

Esta opción está en 2 botones que son el de Siguiente y en el de guardar los datos en la BD. Pero por alguna razón no solo no sale el mensaje si no que pasa a la siguiente pantalla.

```
String nombreComprobar, edadComprobar, ciudadComprobar, codPComprobar, paisComprobar, sexoComprobar;

botonSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nombreComprobar = campoNombre.toString().trim();
            edadComprobar = campoEdad.toString().trim();
            ciudadComprobar = campoCiudad.toString().trim();
            codPComprobar = campoCodPostal.toString().trim();
            paisComprobar = campoPais.toString().trim();
            sexoComprobar = campoSexo.toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nombreComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edadComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(ciudadComprobar) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty(codPComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(paisComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(sexoComprobar)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes insertar todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Intent miIntent1 = new Intent(RegistrarUsuarios.this, VentanaInstrucciones.class);
                startActivity(miIntent1);
            }

        }
    });

    botonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nombreComprobar = campoNombre.toString().trim();
            edadComprobar = campoEdad.toString().trim();
            ciudadComprobar = campoCiudad.toString().trim();
            codPComprobar = campoCodPostal.toString().trim();
            paisComprobar = campoPais.toString().trim();
            sexoComprobar = campoSexo.toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nombreComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edadComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(ciudadComprobar) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty(codPComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(paisComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(sexoComprobar)){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes insertar todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                registrarUsuario();
            }

        }
    });
```

Estos son los botones que comprueban si se han rellenado los campos antes de hacer su acción.

Quería saber como arreglar esto y como bloquear la pantalla si no se han introducido todos los campos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el texto contenido en un `EditText`, o `TextView` debes usar el método `getText().toString()` , ejemplo:

```
myEditText.getText().toString();
```

Te sugiero usar este método el cual valida además de un valor null si el texto ingresado es un espacio.

```
public static boolean isNullorEmpty(String cadena){
    return (cadena == null || cadena.trim().isEmpty());
}
```

y usarlo de esta forma:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nombreComprobar = campoNombre.getText().toString();
            edadComprobar = campoEdad.getText().toString();
            ciudadComprobar = campoCiudad.getText.toString();
            codPComprobar = campoCodPostal.getText.toString();
            paisComprobar = campoPais.getText.toString();
            sexoComprobar = campoSexo.getText.toString();
            if (isNullorEmpty(nombreComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(edadComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(ciudadComprobar) ||
                    isNullorEmpty(codPComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(paisComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(sexoComprobar)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes insertar todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Intent miIntent1 = new Intent(RegistrarUsuarios.this, VentanaInstrucciones.class);
                startActivity(miIntent1);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema principal es que estás usando toString() para obtener la información la información, estos en ese método te devuelven una referencia al objeto con informaciones tales como el id de dicho objeto. La forma correcta es utilizar el método **getText().toString()**;

Una mejor forma de estructurar tu problema es crear un método que te diga que sí hay campos vacíos, así evitas repetir el mismo código para ambos botones.

```
public boolean hayCamposVacios()
{
     String   nombreComprobar = campoNombre.getText().toString();
     String   edadComprobar = campoEdad.getText().toString();


     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nombreComprobar) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edadComprobar))){
          return true;
     }

     return false;

}
```

Comment: ¿Crees que debería meter la función registrarUsuario() dentro del else de la función hayCamposVacios?

Comment: No, simplemente cambia donde hacias TextUtils.isEmpty  por la función y quedará listo.